# how to suppress a group using if condition, if the some vlaues are same (in this case accountid)

Tags: crystal-reports

I just want to supress/ hide the all the of a specific id except the last 
For example id
I have 10 group in a report 
And 4 out of 10 having same accountid and the remaing 6 have diffenrent account id
Now i just want to supress the first 3 groups out of that 4 groups

And in that 4 group it just show me 4th one group and hide first 3 groups out of 4 as well as blank spaces ( if they show blank space after hiding the groups)

So in this way my report will show 7 groups instead of 10 groups

Comment: instead select distinct records

Comment: already tried that but not working